# Custom field in checkout saved in quote_address and sales_order_address not shown in order summary

Tags: magento2, sales-order, custom, checkout-page, guest-checkout

**I have added a custom field to shipping and billing data in the checkout form. It's value is correctly stored in an extra column in tables quote_address and sales_order_address.**

Now the goal is to show the value(s) from this field in the order summary like so: [image]

And I've read somewhere that this can be done by changing the customer's configuration address templates, i.e. the HTML template with something like this:

> {{if custom_var_code}}{{var custom_var_code}}{{/if}}

Only it doesn't work. Clearly I left something out, but I've got no clue what.
**Can anybody enlighten me?**

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This In HTML Section :-**

```
{{depend custom_var_code}}Custom Var Code: {{var custom_var_code}}{{/depend}}
```

Depending on the template type, you can use `<br/>` to create new lines.

Comment: Tried that, but alas it didn't work. I see the value in tables quote_address and sales_order_address, so I know it's there. Also if I change a value from e.g. telephone field by hand in the sales_order_table, this change is reflected in the relevant backend view, but my custom field does not show. I am at my wit's end with this.